# I want print array value multiple times

Tags: javascript, postman

```
{
  "ID": 0,
  "OrganizationId": "{{OrgID}}",
  "Name":"{{TagName}}",
  "Type": 1,
  "AppliesTo": 1,
  "Values": [{"Id":1,"Text":"Level1","HODEmail":"","IsDeleted":false}]
}
```

In above JSON I want to print the values array up to hundred times in which Id and Text field value should be increasing/unique every time.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the expected output? What is the "uniqueness" logic? What is your current attempt you're stuck with?

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a while loop and the `Object.assign()` method to dynamically add items to an empty `obj.Values` array:

```js
// Defines simplified object and template for array items
const obj = { ID: 0, Values: [] }
const defaultItem = { Id: 1, Text : "Level1" , HODEmail : "" }

// Starts counter at 0
let i = 0;

// iterates until counter exceeds 100
while(++i <= 100){

  // Creates next item to add to Values array
  const nextItem = Object.assign(

    {},                          // Starts with an empty object
    defaultItem,                 // Gives it all the properties of `defaultItem`
    { Id: i, Text: `Level${i}` } // Overwrites the `Id` and `Text` properties
  );

  // Adds the newly creates item to obj.Values
  obj.Values.push(nextItem);
}

// Prints the resulting object
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

The most difficult part of your question is that you want the id and text field value to be increasing / unique. Not sure what unique means, but we can achieve what we want by `sorting` our array.

First, we'll parse the JSON into an object, then we'll sort the `Values` array, then we'll print the items in `Values` in the desired order

```
let o = JSON.parse(`{ "ID": 0, "OrganizationId": "{{OrgID}}", "Name":"{{TagName}}", "Type": 1, "AppliesTo": 1, "Values": [{"Id":1,"Text":"Level1","HODEmail":"","IsDeleted":false}] }`);


let sorted = o.Values.sort((a,b) => {
    // simply return the element (a or b) that should come first
    return a.Id < b.Id // can also factor in uniqueness here
})

for (let j = 0; j < sorted.length && j < 100; j++) {
    console.log(sorted[j])
}
```